# Automatically get values of all element inside a div with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have a main div and inside of this, there are a lot of input text and radio button.
Like this:

```
<div id="mainDiv">
   <input type="text" name="text-1" /> <br/>

   <input type="radio" name="radio-1" />Yes
   <input type="radio" name="radio-1" />No <br/>

   <input type="text" name="text-2" /> <br/>
   <input type="text" name="text-3" /> <br/>
</div>
<img src="img/img.gif" onclick="getAllValues();" />
```

I want to define the function `getAllValues()` in jQuery to get all values in `mainDiv` and  save them in a string.
It is possible?

Comment: Have you taken a look at `.serialize()` (http://api.jquery.com/serialize/)? Does that fit your bill? If not, why?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

To achieve this you can select all the form fields and use `map()` to create an array from their values, which can be retrieved based on their `type`. Try this:

```
function getAllValues() {
    var inputValues = $('#mainDiv :input').map(function() {
        var type = $(this).prop("type");

        // checked radios/checkboxes
        if ((type == "checkbox" || type == "radio") && this.checked) { 
           return $(this).val();
        }
        // all other fields, except buttons
        else if (type != "button" && type != "submit") {
            return $(this).val();
        }
    })
    return inputValues.join(',');
}
```

The `if` statement could be joined together here, but I left them separate for clarity.

Comment: It works with input text, but with the radio buttons that I would take only the selected values. Thankyou rory! ​​

Comment: `type != "button" || type != "submit"` Shouldn't this be `&&` instead of `||`? Otherwise you'll pick up everything.

Comment: @JonWyatt Thanks! You're right - the first person in 7.5 years to notice :)

Answer (score 7):

Try something like that:

```
function getAllValues() {
  var allVal = '';
  $("#mainDiv > input").each(function() {
    allVal += '&' + $(this).attr('name') + '=' + $(this).val();
  });
  alert(allVal);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is solution which is building you a JSON string. It's getting the values of the text fields, check boxes and select elements:

```
function buildRequestStringData(form) {
    var select = form.find('select'),
        input = form.find('input'),
        requestString = '{';
    for (var i = 0; i < select.length; i++) {
        requestString += '"' + $(select[i]).attr('name') + '": "' +$(select[i]).val() + '",';
    }
    if (select.length > 0) {
        requestString = requestString.substring(0, requestString.length - 1);
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
        if ($(input[i]).attr('type') !== 'checkbox') {
            requestString += '"' + $(input[i]).attr('name') + '":"' + $(input[i]).val() + '",';
        } else {
            if ($(input[i]).attr('checked')) {
                requestString += '"' + $(input[i]).attr('name') +'":"' + $(input[i]).val() +'",';
            }
        }
    }
    if (input.length > 0) {
        requestString = requestString.substring(0, requestString.length - 1);
    }
    requestString += '}';
    return requestString;
}
```

You can call the function like this:

```
buildRequestStringData($('#mainDiv'))
```

And the result http://jsfiddle.net/p7hbT/